# Sorting formatted dates in R

Tags: r, sorting, date, formatting

I have a dataframe of dates and numeric values in R. The dates are all the first of the month and the values are a number associated with that month

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-02-01","2017-03-01","2017-04-01")), 
                 val = c(-5600,7000,4200,-2000))
```

I'd like to stick this through `DT::datatable()`, which is my new favourite thing. However, I'd like to have the output formatted nicely, thousand separators, nice dates etc.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(val = formatC(val, big.mark=","))
datatable(df)
```

This turns `val` into a character vector, although `datatable()` is apparently able to recognise that it's really a number and sort appropriately using the arrows in the header. So far so good.

However the issue comes when I try to format the date as MMM YY.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(date = format(date, "%b %y"))

datatable(df)
```

This turns date into a character vector as well - the values look like "Jan 17" etc. Everything looks fine, only trouble is when I go to sort by `date`, it doesn't recognise the values as months and puts them in alphabetical rather than chronological order.

Is there any way of reformatting the dates, either prior to or whilst passing them to `datatable()`, to keep the "date-ness" of the variable and allow it to be sorted appropriately? Failing that, is there another package that outputs interactive tables and is better at sorting?

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: I think you should avoid changing the class of your data columns and instead construct a print-method that you will use at at the time of any output.

Answer (score 0):

you can take help of lubridate package. 
And do the stuff using this function.

What you need to do is take month and date separately into account.

```
    library(lubridate)
date_conversion<-function(df){

  months<-month(df$date,label = T)
  years<-year(df$date)
  months_years<-paste(months, years, sep = " ")
  df[1]<-months_years
  df[order(row.names(df),decreasing = F),]

}
```

hope this helps you .... :)

Answer (score 0):

`DataTables` as integrated in R by the `DT` package has options to format numeric and date variables while maintaining the proper sort order.

Below, I will discuss three different options:

```
library(DT)
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-02-01","2017-03-01","2017-04-01")), 
                 val = c(-5600,7000,4200,-12000))
```

Please, note that I've deliberately choosen to change the last value in column `val` to demonstrate a pitfall in using `formatC()`.

```
# OP's own formatting
df$val_chr <- formatC(df$val, big.mark=",")
df$date_chr <- format(df$date, "%b %y")
# copy columns to demonstrate DT formatting
df$val_dt <- df$val
df$date_dt <- df$date
# ISO 8601 year-month format as alternative
df$dat_iso <- format(df$date, "%Y-%m")

# create DT object and apply DT formatting
datatable(df) %>%  formatCurrency("val_dt", "") %>% formatDate("date_dt", "toDateString")
```

[image]

Note that `val_dt` has been formatted nicely as expected and is right justified.  In contrast, `val_chr` is left justified with the thousands separators not aligned. In addition, `formatC()` has recognized that `val` is of type double and has used the "g" format by default. According to the description of the `format`parameter in  `?formatC` *Default is "d" for integers, "g" for reals.* So, we do get

```
    formatC(12000L, big.mark=",")
    #[1] "12,000"
```

but

```
    formatC(12000, big.mark=",")
    #[1] "1.2e+04"
```

Sorting by `date_dt` within the `datatables` object by clicking on the small arrows symbols at the right side of the column headers works as expected in contrast to `date_chr`. Unfortunately, the number of available methods for `formatDate()` [is limited](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) and doesn't include the desired month-year format. (There is a [`datetime` plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime) which *converts date / time source data into one suitable for display* but I haven't explored that in detail.)

Column `date_iso` shows the  [abbreviated ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) as a third option. This is my favoured format (which I do use alot also for aggregating by month) because

- it always sorts correctly, even for several years,
- it doesn't depend on the current locale, so it works in any language,
- it is short while being unambiguous,
- and it is an international standard.

#### Addendum

The `formattable` package does also have various formatter functions and can create `DataTables`:

```
library(formattable)
as.datatable(formattable(df))
```

Comment: Thanks, `formatDate` and its relatives look really useful, if only there were more built-in formats! I'll take a look at the plugin and see where I get.

Comment: The `datetime` plugin seems to offer different formats but I haven't have time yet to integrate. If you do, please, post as answer!